# WPF Style does not affect certain properties

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, styles, dynamicresource

I've got a `Style` specified for `Paragraph` as part of my `FlowDocumentReader`'s Resources section:

```
<FlowDocumentReader>
   <FlowDocumentReader.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSteelBlue" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightSteelBlue" />
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.0" />
         <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Path=MyFontSize}" />
      </Style>
   </FlowDocumentReader.Resources>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```

I've got a .xaml file which contains my `FlowDocument` and it has some `Paragraph`s which are defined as so:

```
<Paragraph Style='{DynamicResource myStyle}">
    Stuff here
</Paragraph>
```

The problem that I have is that `Foreground` doesn't apply to the text (it shows as Black rather than LightSteelBlue) and the `FontSize` does not change when the `MyFontSize` property is modified.

I've checked the property value in the code behind and it is set but it doesn't result in a change in the UI.

This seems to only be an issue with the `FlowDocument` if it is loaded into the `FlowDocumentReader` at runtime.  If the XAML is explicitly placed inside the `FlowDocumentReader` in the .xaml file, the `Foreground` is the correct color and the `FontSize` changes based on the property setting.

Ideas?

---

**Solved:**

As I wrote in my answer below, by moving the `Style` block into the Resources section of the `FlowDocument` itself resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved this problem by moving the Style blocks out of the FlowDocumentReader Resources and into the Resources section of the FlowDocument itself. The resulting FlowDocument looks something like so:

```
<FlowDocument>
   <FlowDocument.Resources>
      <Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightSteelBlue" />
         <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightSteelBlue" />
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1.0" />
         <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic" />
         <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding Path=MyFontSize}" />
      </Style>
   </FlowDocument.Resources>
   <Paragraph Style="{DynamicResource myStyle}">
      Stuff here
   </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting foreground for your paragraph directly? it must be a different propety/attached property which manages contents foreground.

Comment: Yes, if I set paragraph.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), it will change the color.